# DotNet Core MVC Arithmetic operation resulted in an overflow. After Controller creation

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-core

Using latest dotnet core MVC on Visual Studio 2015 Enterprise edition. Built a new Controller, using EntityFramework and MVC Views, which scaffolded no problem.  However, when I go to the Index View, I get this:

> An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request. 
>   OverflowException: Arithmetic operation resulted in an overflow.
>   TryGetConnection

Here's the stack:

> System.OverflowException: Arithmetic operation resulted in an
>   overflow.    at
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection
>   owningObject, UInt32 waitForMultipleObjectsTimeout, Boolean
>   allowCreate, Boolean onlyOneCheckConnection, DbConnectionOptions
>   userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)    at
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection
>   owningObject, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions
>   userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)    at
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection
>   owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions
>   userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection, DbConnectionInternal&
>   connection)    at
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal(DbConnection
>   outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory,
>   TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(TaskCompletionSource`1
>   retry)    at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open()    at
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.Open()
>   at
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.Internal.SqlServerDatabaseCreator.Exists(Boolean
>   retryOnNotExists)    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.EntityFrameworkCore.DatabaseErrorPageMiddleware.d__6.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.EntityFrameworkCore.DatabaseErrorPageMiddleware.d__6.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.d__6.MoveNext()

Comment: Run your project in debug mode, and then catch error raising line, and then share with us

Comment: would you mind to share with us the line that causing the error. Please share Action Link alongside with the error prone line.

Comment: Whenever I go to the Albums Views, like so: http://localhost:1815/Albums, it gives me an Internal Server error and this:

Comment: I am facing the same issue.
Did you get any solution?

Comment: Update VisualStudio, it works for me.